# Is it possible to have a union type constructor object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code used for run time type checking by vue.js

```
props: {
  foo: Object | Array
}
```

Here Object and Array are runtime objects, it is used to do type checking at runtime by vue.js. This doesn't actually work because | is interpreted as an arithmetic operator since Object and Array are values rather than types.

Is there someway of constructing an object that can represent the object or array type?

Comment: TypeScript does no type checking in runtime. The code you posted is JavaScript.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. As @MadaraUchiha said, there's no type checking at runtime. What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: Yeah I understand. Typescript does not do runtime type checking. Vue.js does. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component

It uses the constructor to do runtime typechecking.

Comment: Actually there is some runtime checking via type guards. Search for type guards on this page: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
props: {
  foo: {
    type: [Object, Array]
  }
}
```

or more generally

```
props: {
  foo: {
    type: [Object as () => YourTypeScriptType, Array, String]
  }
}
```

It will be like

```
type FooProps = YourTypeScriptType | Array | string
```